# By converging integrals does not follow that $\int |f_n - f | \rightarrow 0$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal M_{\lambda^*})$ and $f, f_n: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$.

I know that the following statement is not true in general:

> If $f_n, f$ are integrable and $\int f_n(x) \rightarrow \int f(x)$ , then: $ \int | f_n - f | d \lambda \rightarrow 0 $.

But is there any example which really shows that the statement is not true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f_n=\chi_{[0,n]}-\chi_{[-n,0]}$ and $f=0$.

Then, $\int fd\lambda=\int\chi_{[0,n]}d\lambda-\int\chi_{[-n,0]}d\lambda=n-n=0=\int fd\lambda$.

But $\int|f_n-f|d\lambda=\int|f_n|d\lambda=\int\chi_{[0,n]}d\lambda+\int\chi_{[-n,0]}d\lambda=n+n=2n\not\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Take any odd integrable function $f$ ($\neq 0$) on $\mathbb R$ and let $f_n=-f$ for  all $n$.